# How do I calculate the driving distance between 2 places along with a map in php

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I am looking for **driving distance between two address/postcodes with displaying both on Google Map** in php

**I have search a lot of Scripts but most of them calculation distance only. I also want the both address along Google map also**.

like this http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/distance-finder/source-distance-finder-google-maps.php

But this link calculate the "straight line distance" between two address and also show them on map

Please help me, **i don't want straight line. I want driving calculation alone with map.(The script also show address on Google map**)

Comment: My advice is to read the code for the link you provided. It's quite readable. distance = "The distance between the two points on the chosen route is: "+response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the API, I suggest you 'google' the google API for specifics, the documentation for google maps v3+ is awesome, you should have no problem if you're not reaching way outside your knowledge base.

and +1 @HeitorChang for that comment, I didn't see it.

Comment: No Help from above ansewer. Please post only meaningful answer. The code "The distance between the two points on the chosen route is: "+response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text" never execute in above acript.

Comment: Try running a JavaScript console/debugger with the page and post what errors you see. It looks like the code I copied works for both Relic and me, are you seeing a yellow line and purple polyline? For me it shows "The distance between the two points on the chosen route is: 6.9 mi
The aproximative driving time is: 16 mins"

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much perfect. Maybe the data you're 'fetching' is not what you think. Double check your request as well as the full response before doing any work on it. `console.log()` baby!

Comment: No, If you check that link, it is not working here. Do you have any sample code link that i can integrate ??????. Thanks for replying

Comment: It wasn't too hard to isolate the driving distance http://jsfiddle.net/39KKu/ you should see 1.3 miles. Change location1, 2 to get new directions. If this doesn't work I can't help you any more.

Comment: *wipes brow* I was starting to think there was some other random issue going on.